# How to call authentication based api from dialogflow?

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es

How can I call API which requires  **token**?
Suppose I have an API which returns a list of students but to get a list, I have to send authorization token. how can I call such API on dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an authorization token in the headers that are send to your webhook.
These settings can be found under the Fulfillment settings in Dialogflow. Here you should provide a key and value. In this case value is the token you identify with and the key value depends on the configuration of the API.

More info on webhook configuration can be found [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/configure).

Comment: Thanks @Jordi. Can we do all of this with java i.e adding headers?

Comment: I dont think you can set the headers through code on Dialogflow. When you set them in the Fulfillment settings the headers will be added to the call to your webhook that is made by Dialogflow. No coding required